# Derivatives of exponential functions and number $e$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, algebra-precalculus, limits, derivatives

How to prove that this thing $ e = (1 + h)^\frac{1}{h}, h \rightarrow 0 \iff (1 + \frac n)^n, n \rightarrow \infty$
 goes to some exact value? Is there a proof of this, and if possible, intuition? (#)

If we want to find solution of equation $\frac{d}{dx} [a^x] = a^x$ we would easly see that solution is limit above, namely $e.$ But why is that? Is there intuitive reason why that golden value is, on a first sight, jut random irrational number? It's obvious that this 1 in limit is base-value, when time equals 0 ($e^0 = 1$). But I don't see conection in the rest of the formula (limit) :(

Also, I looked why $e^x = (1 + \frac{x}{n})^n, n \rightarrow \infty,$ (##) and here goes reasoning (I will always suppose that n goest to infinity):
Wee see that $e^{\frac{x}{n}} = 1.$ But also $1 + \frac{x}{n} = 1.$ Therefore, we get (##). Of course, this is just wrong: same "reasoning" can be done with any positive base. I must say that now I am confused: for very small $h$ we *would* have, for example when base is 3, $3^h = 1 + h$?? (###)

Can you prove (explain) questions above: (#), (###) and can you give me intuitive and clear picture of *why* we got that strange limit. I can get that number *with algebra*, but just can't with imagination and logic.

Comment: Bear in mind that $e$ was *defined* to be a solution to these types of questions.  $\lim_{h\to 0} \frac {a^{x+h}-a^x}h = \lim\frac {a^x*a^h-a^x}{h}=a^x\lim\frac {a^h-1}h$. $\lim \frac {a^h-1}h$ is a constant value depending only on $a$ and not on $x$ so $\frac {da^x}{dx}= a^x*C_a$ for a constant based on $a$.  It's reasonable there is some $a$ where $C_a=1$ and $[a^x]'=a^x$.  That $a$ turns out has to be $\lim_{n\to\infty}(1 + \frac 1n)^n$ and we *define* $e$ to be that number.

Comment: "on a first sight, jut random irrational number?" there is *nothing* random about $e$.  This like saying why is the circumference divided by the diameter equal to the random irrational number $\pi$?  Coincidence.  No.  $\pi$ is *defined* to be the answer.

Comment: @fleablood, I did not mean on $e$ as its decimals (because it is again a human convention) but the above formula (definition of the number $e$). So by solving the equation above we get that limit, formula. Algebraically everything is clear. But I lack the intuition and logic behind that formula. Where is conncention between compund interest and "selfderivation" ($\frac{d}{dx}[e^x] = e^x$)? In other words, were we able to deduce by common sense (without algebra) what number we would get (its formula)? Why did we get that number, is there any intuition about that?

Comment: "In other words, were we able to deduce by common sense (without algebra) what number we would get (its formula)?"  We knew we'd get *some* number.  But no idea which one. $\lim_{n\to \infty}(1+\frac 1n)^n=\lim_{h\to\infty}(1+h)^{\frac 1h}$ equals *SOMETHING* but we have no idea what call it $W$. Whatever $W$ is $[W^x]'= W^x\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{W^h-1}$ and $\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{W^h-1}h=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{(\lim_{h\to 0}(1+h)^{\frac 1h})^h-1}h=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac {(1+h)-1}h= 1$.  So $[W^x]'=W^x$. We give $W$ the name $e$. We have no idea what value $e$ is, we just know it exists.

Comment: @fleablood, I didn't think on that and maybe I expressed myself in a bad way. Imagine being asked by a (talented) child: What does formula $(1 + h)^\frac{1}{h}$ when $h \rightarrow 0$ (original definition of $e$) have to do with very small increase along the $x$ axis *causing* increase by $e^x$ in hight, $y$ axis? What would you say to him without using algebra?

Comment: I *would* use algebra.  $\frac {rise}{run}=\frac {f(y)-f(x)}{y-x}=\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}h=\frac {a^{x+h}-a^x}h=\frac {a^xa^h-a^x}h=a^x\cdot\frac {a^h-1}h$.  So $\frac{da^x}{dx} = a^x\lim_{h\to 0}\frac {a^h-1}h$.  Now if $a=e = \lim_{h\to 0}(1+h)^{\frac 1h}$ then $\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{a^h-1}h=\lim (\frac {(\lim (1+h)^{\frac 1h})^h -1}h) = \lim (\frac {((1+h)^{\frac 1h})^h -1}h = \lim\frac{(1+h)-1}h =\lim \frac hh = 1$.  And that's it.  $\frac {de^x}{dx} e^x*\lim(...) = e^x*1 = e^x$.

Comment: The "magic" of exponetials is that $b^{x+y}= b^xb^y$.  It takes addition in the input and turns it into multiplication in the output.  So and incremental change to the input of an exponential function will be proportional to the value of the function itself at that point.  That is if $x\to x+h$ then $a^x \to a^x\cdot K_h$ where $K_h$ is the constant $a^h$.  So the derivative of $a^x$ will be $C*a^x$ for some value $C=\lim \frac{K_h -1}h$.  The larger $a$ is the larger $C$ is and the small $a$ is the smaller $C$ will be.  There must be some value where $C=1$.  That value is $e$.

Comment: Now why should $e$ where $\lim \frac{e^h-1}h = 1$ be the value $e=\lim {1+\frac 1n}^n$  Well, those are inverses of each other.  If $h = \frac 1n$ then $[(1+\frac 1n)^n]^h= (1+\frac 1n)$ And so $\lim \frac{e^h-1}h = \lim \frac{1+\frac 1n - 1}h =\lim \frac {\frac 1n}h = 1$.  So $e = \lim(1+\frac 1n)^n$ just plain works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The magic of exponents is that doing addition in the input $$b^{x+y}$$ results in multiplication in the output $$b^x\times b^y$$.

As a result, an incremental change of $h$ will resultion in a change from $$x_0 \to x_0 + h$$ will result in an output change $$b^{x_0}\to b^{x_0}\times b^h$$ which is a *proportion* change based on the current value of $b^{x_0}$.

Now derivatives express a rate of change and with exponential powers that rate of change is proportional to the current value, so intuitively we should have, if $f(x) = b^x$ that $f'(x) = C_bb^x$ for some constant $C_b$.  And indeed we *do*:

$$f'(x) =\lim\limits_{h\to 0}\frac {f(x+h) - f(x)}h =\lim\limits_{h\to 0}\frac {b^{x+h} - b^x}h=\lim\limits_{h\to 0}\frac{b^x*b^h-b^x}h=b^x\lim\limits_{h\to 0}\frac{b^h-1}h = C_b b^x$$ where $C_b = \lim\limits_{h\to 0}\frac {b^h - 1}h$.

....

Now if we think about this "increases is proportion to current" value is the the entire idea of interest.  You have $P(x_k)$ in principal at some time.  A period of time passe and you value increases by a factor of $r$ so you gain $r*P(x_k)$ and your new value is $P(x_{k+1}) = P(x_k) + r*(x_k)$.  And we recursively compund it to the formula that after $n$ units of time our initial investment of $P(0)$ will be $P(n) = P(0)\times (1+r)^n$.

......

Now back to $f(x) = b^x$ and $f'(x) = b^xC_b$.  The larger the base, $b$, the quicker the rate of growth so the large $b$ is, the larger $C_b$ is.  The smaller $b$ is, the smaller $C_b$ is.

Now if $a = 1$ then $f(x) = a^x = 1$ and $f'(x) = 1^x*C_1=0$ and $C_1 = 0$ and if $b$ is really huge there is no limit to how large $C_b$ can be.

So there must be some value $e$ where $C_e = 1$ and $f(x) = e^x$ so $f'(x) = e^xC_e = e^x*1 = e^x$.

So

$1=C_e = \lim\limits_{h\to 0}\frac {e^h-1}h$.  So we can estimate $e$ by solving the equation $\lim\limits_{h\to 0}\frac {e^h-1}h= 1$.

That is for *teensy* $h$.

$\frac {e^h-1}h \approx 1$

$e^h-1 \approx h$

$e^h \approx 1+h$

No lets replace *teensy* $h$ with $\frac 1n$ for *big* $n$.

$e^{\frac 1n} \approx (1+\frac 1n)$ and

$e \approx (1+\frac 1n)^n$.

And that's it:  $e =\lim\limits_{n\to \infty} (1+\frac 1n)^n$.

...

Which.... if fits into the continuous compound interest aspect very nicely.